# Java regex to find all words in a splitted url path

Tags: java, regex, url

So i have this url path which i splitted by "/".
Example:
Complite url path: https://www.uni.it/it/ateneo-org_plot-pesc/organ/organi-amm/rettore-o_0-rect
Splitted path looks like this:

```
it
ateneo-org_plot-
organ
organi-amm
rettore-o_0-rect
```

The output i want is:

```
it
ateneo
org
plot
organ
organi
amm
rettore
o
0
rect
```

I tried something like this:

```
public static List<String> extractAllWordsFromUrlPath(String link) {
    List<String> splittedUrlPath = splitLinkPath(link);
    List<String> urlWords = new ArrayList<String>();
    if(splittedUrlPath!=null && splittedUrlPath.size()>0) {
        Pattern linkWordsPattern = Pattern.compile("[-_]?[a-z]+[-_]?");
        for(String sPath: splittedUrlPath) {


        Matcher lwpm = linkWordsPattern.matcher(sPath);
        while(lwpm.find()) {
            urlWords.add(lwpm.group());
        }
        }
    }

    return urlWords;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to remove the first component of the URL before the first path separator.  Then, split the remaining string on `[/_-]`:

```
String url = "https://www.uni.it/it/ateneo-org_plot-pesc/organ/organi-amm/rettore-o_0-rect"; 
URL theURL = new URL(url);
String path = theURL.getPath();
String[] parts = path.split("[/_-]");

for (String part : parts)  {
    System.out.println(part + " ");
}

it ateneo org plot organ organi amm rettore o 0 rect
```

Note that I used `java.net.URL` to extract the path from the input URL.  We could also try doing this via regex, but it might be error prone or not cover all possible types of URLs.

Comment: This is a great answer, he should definitely use URL.getPath() to avoid re-inventing the wheel when it comes to decoding the url so I upvoted it. My answer just expands it to finish your prototype, i.e. filter-handling the empty strings, dealing with potential null values, handling an obvious exception and some naming). Is it OK if we merge the answers, i.e. if you update yours?

Comment: I was actually looking for this :D

Answer (score 1):

I offer my answer, with the emphasis on "minimal" changes to your code. Note that this code isn't really "production-ready" and definitely needs certain re-think on numerous parts, including static method usage, handling exceptions, etc, but will definitely be a great prototype for you (which I presume your snippet is as well!). It is also created in such way for you to easily debug through code.

```
public static List<String> extractAllWordsFromUrlPath(String link) throws MalformedURLException {

    String path = new URL(link).getPath();
    String regex = "[/_-]";  // set somewhere in config file, input as method argument?
    String[] extractedWords = path.split(regex);
    List<String> result = Arrays.asList(extractedWords);

    return result.stream().filter(w -> (w != null && w.length() > 0)).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Method returns List just to keep up with your decision.
Note that **streams are java 8 feature** and there may be some over-engineering feeling in that code, i.e. when you look at part with ensuring that the list doesn't contain a null-value String.
Also keep in mind that **Arrays.asList() returns as immutable list**, just in case if you ever utilize it for casting an array to list in some other parts of your code.

You can verify this code by utilizing the `for(String word : parsedWords )` solution in your other method, so you can also combine it with @Tim Bergenstein's solution, so I also upwoted his answer, it gives a great basis and I just expanded it to handle the empty strings, null values, quick exception handling and some naming norms:

```
//code in your other method, of main class, just for testing
List<String> parsedWords = extractAllWordsFromUrlPath("http://www.google.com/asd/asd/dfg/kjg");
for(String word: parsedWords) {
    System.out.println(word + " ");
}
```